# ¿ Cómo hago funcionar "datepicker" en mi proyecto de angular 2?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, datepicker, inspinia

Estoy usando `angular2` y obtengo este error al cargar la pagina.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (respuestas:44)
>       at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:408)
>       at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:408)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:424)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
>       at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:486)
>       at timer (zone.js:1540)

Mis scripts estan asi:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/inspinia.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/pace.min.js"></script>

<!-- Data picker -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Necesito ayuda, ya intente de todo

Answer (score 0):

Estas teniendo conflicto en dos librerías

1. `<script src="assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` puede contener un Widget `.datepicker()` mas informacion [aqui](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), y esta causa conflicto con **bootstrap-datepicker**.
2. `<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>` es una librería de jQuery que tiene un método `.datepicker()`

Entonces ya sea que utilices **jQuery-ui** o utilices el plugin de **jQuery** eliminando la referencia a **jQuery-ui**.

---

Otra solución seria poner el `.datepicker()` en modo no conflicto de la siguiente manera:

```
$(function(){
    var datepicker = $.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
    $.fn.bootstrapDatepicker = datepicker;  
    $("#dp3").bootstrapDatepicker();    
});
```

---

Si la librería jQuery-ui es una librería personalizada que no incluye los Widgets (esta la puedes obtener de [aquí](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.12.1&components=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)), es posible que la librería **bootstrap-datepicker** no este completa o este mal descargada